# Alter generated link of PagedList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination, pagedlist

I'm using the PagedList made by TroyGoode: https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/
but I want it to render other output than I currently have.

The default output is: *www.mypage.com/mytopic?page=3*

But what I want to produce is: *www.mypage.com/mytopic/3/*

The code I'm currently using is taken from the example at: 
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

```
@Html.PagedListPager( Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter }) )
```

Does anyone know how I get this component to add another form of paging to my Url's?

Comment: What's with all the downvoting? Am I missing something here?

Comment: the downvoters probably felt you should have been able to answer this question from research. I agree with their sentiment, but don't feel a down votes were warranted. They could have killed 2 birds with 1 stone by pointing out that you need a route for this and made a smart @ss comment **(saving you 50 rep)**

Comment: After seeing the answers and figuring out how simple it is to solve this, i understand that. But, as i'm just learing a bit of MVC, i really didn't have a clue on how this component and the routing setup were working together. So, i'm still happy trading a few points for this knowledge.

Comment: You apparently got 2 upvotes and 3 downvotes. Combined with answer accepted, you actually gained 6 rep pnts. That's not including the bounty, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to the answer of cem: You might want to add the `sortOrder` and `currentFilter` parameters as well:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "mytopic",
    "mytopic/{page}/{sortOrder}/{currentFilter}",
    new 
        { 
            controller = "Home", 
            action = "Index", 
            page = 1, 
            sortOrder = UrlParameter.Optional, 
            currentFilter =  UrlParameter.Optional
        }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's just a basic route mapping.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "mytopic",
    "mytopic/{page}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", page = 1 }
);
```